# When 1 column is null make other column equal to a certain number error

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I am getting an error with this line

```
case 
   when [sm] is null 
      then countofMk = 0 
   else countofmake 
end as max2
```

Error is :

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Can anyone please advise what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the same data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
     sku varchar(50), 
     [gtitle] varchar(50), 
     [mk] varchar(50),  
     [md] varchar(50),
     [sm] varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (sku, [gtitle], [mk],[md],[sm])
VALUES ('F92', 'Game1', 'b100', 'xbox', 'pilot'),
        ('F92', 'Game1', 'b100', 'xbox', 'ex'),
        ('F92', 'Game2', 'b100', 'xbox', 'null'),
        ('F92', 'Game2', 'b100', 'xbox', 'LLL');

------- query       
WITH mixmax AS
(
    SELECT 
        sku, [gtitle], [mk], [md], [sm],
        COUNT([mk]) AS countofMk
    FROM 
        Table1
    GROUP BY  
        sku, mk, md, sm, gtitle
)
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN [sm] IS NULL 
          THEN countofMk = 0 
       ELSE countofmake 
    END AS  max2,  --- getting error here
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY sku, countofMk DESC, COALESCE([md], ''), COALESCE([sm], '') ASC) AS RowNum
FROM 
    mixmax;
```

Here is the intended result: when one column is null make the other 0

```
        sku gtitle  mk  md  sm  countofMk   max2    RowNum
        F92 Game1   b100    xbox    ex  1   1   1
        F92 Game2   b100    xbox    LLL 1   1   2
        F92 Game2   b100    xbox    null    1   0   3
        F92 Game1   b100    xbox    pilot   1   1   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include condition in the original query

```
WITH mixmax AS 
(
    SELECT sku
        , [gtitle]
        , [mk]
        , [md]
        , [sm]
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN [sm] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [mk] END) as countofMk
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY sku, mk ,md, sm, gtitle
)
```

`countofMk` will be `0` for group where `[sm]` is null

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support boolean types.  I'm not sure what you intend.  Perhaps:

```
(case when [sm] is null then 0 else countofmake end) as max2,  --- getting error here
```

Comment: I am basically trying to say: if sm is null than make countofMk 0 otherwise use countofMk

Comment: Thhen all you need is `countofMk = case when [sm] is null then 0 else countofMk 
 end` @Wsi

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of two columns on the same line. You need to do it twice, once for each column...

```
,max2 = case when [sm] is null then countofMk else countofmake end
```

or maybe

```
,max2 = case when [sm] is null then 0 else countofmake end
```

Or for setting two columns

```
,countofMk = case when [sm] is null then 0 end
,case when [sm] is null then 0 else countofmake end as max2
```

**EDIT**

```
countofMk = case when [sm] is null then 0 else countofmake end
```